# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger

Tags: java, spring, logging

I am trying to run a Spring Application but it keeps throwing this error:

"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger"

Below is the stack trace of the error.

```
2020-10-05 12:52:34.835 ERROR 20412 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at com.mis.serverdata.utils.STWLogger.<init>(STWLogger.java:26) ~[ServerSharedUtils-1.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.mis.serverdata.utils.STWLogger.getLogger(STWLogger.java:35) ~[ServerSharedUtils-1.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.moveinsync.routeconfiguration.application.services.RouteConfigurationServiceAmazonS3Impl.getRoutingParameters(RouteConfigurationServiceAmazonS3Impl.java:102) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.moveinsync.routeconfiguration.application.controllers.RouteConfigurationController.getConfiguration(RouteConfigurationController.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_265]
```

This is the **getRoutingParameters** method in **RouteConfigurationServiceAmazonS3Impl** class where the error is happening on the *STWLogger* line. I don't know how to fix this. Anyone?

```
    @Override
    public RoutingParameters getRoutingParameters(String businessUnit) throws Exception {
        RoutingParameters params = null;
        String content = getRouteConfigurationData(businessUnit,
                Constants.ROUTE_PARAMETER_FILENAME);
        if (content == null) {
            STWLogger.getLogger().debug("No Parameter Configuration found for " + businessUnit + "\nFetching Configuration for Default for businessUnit ");
            content = getRouteConfigurationData(Constants.ROUTE_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT_BUSINESSUNIT, Constants.ROUTE_PARAMETER_FILENAME);
            if (content == null) {
                return params;
            }
            params = GsonUtils.getGson().fromJson(content, RoutingParameters.class);
            saveRoutingParameters(businessUnit, params);
            return params;
        }
        params = GsonUtils.getGson().fromJson(content, RoutingParameters.class);
        return params;
    }
```

**Update**: I have made the changes based on the 2nd approach of the 1st answer given below, but the error persists.

Below is the updated pom.xml file for my application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.moveinsync.routeconfiguration</groupId>
    <artifactId>RouteConfigurationCRUD</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RouteConfigurationCRUD</name>
    <description>Spring Application for Route Configuration</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- MoveInSync Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.moveinsync.routeconfiguration</groupId>
            <artifactId>mis-routeconfiguration-model</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.moveinsync.routeconfiguration</groupId>
            <artifactId>mis-routeconfiguration-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SLF4J-API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Link SLF4J and log4j2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-context -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>theMainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Could you post the building configuration (`pom.xml` or the `build.gradle`/`build.gradle.kts`) you are using for your application?

Comment: I have added the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. The faulty line here is:

```java
STWLogger.getLogger().debug("No Parameter Configuration found for " + businessUnit + "\nFetching Configuration for Default for businessUnit ");
```

I cannot find the source code of the `STWLogger` class to confirm by a direct analysis, but it seems from the stacktrace that it tries to instantiate the logging system explicitly through Log4j, instead of relying on the standard logging API SLF4J that would select the appropriate logging system at runtime.

The problem here is that you do not have Log4j available with the standard configuration of Spring Boot that you applied. Indeed Spring Boot will import and use Logback as the default logging solution in your classpath, provided by the starter `spring-boot-starter-logging` that is a dependency of the starter `spring-boot-starter-web` you use in you `pom.xml`.

You have two solutions in my opinion.

1. Replace the faulty line by a call to the SLF4J API, that will use Logback automatically behind. It could be something like:

```java
package org.mypackage;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class TestLog {
    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestLog.class);
    
    public void test() {
        LOGGER.info("Your log.");
    }
}
```

2. Replace Logback with Log4j in you Spring Boot application. You can follow these guides to do so:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging#log4j2-configuration-logging

Comment: I tried option 2 but unfortunately, that did not work out for me. can you please tell me step by step what exactly shall I do for option 1?

Comment: I have followed the second approach using the link which you share but the error persists. Also, I have made a few changes in my pom.xml file. Could you please have a look and help me out? Thanks!

Comment: You can try the first approach. Simply use the imports I set in my example at the top of your file, create the `LOGGER` class member under the class of this file, and replace your call of `STWLogger.getLogger().debug(...` by `LOGGER.debug(...`.